# Get-ADuser and nested AD groups

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am working with a script to notify users of expiring passwords but I am having some problems getting results back for nested groups. My script will filter users who are a member of `Parent-Test`. I will not have any users who are a member of this directly, they will be members of `Child01-Test` and `Child02-Test`. `Child01` and `Child02` are members of Parent-Test.

Is there a way to do this using `Get-ADUser` or should I be using something like `Get-ADGroupMember`?

```
$smtpServer="mail.company.com"
$expireindays = 10
$ADGroup ="CN=Parent-test,OU=Groups,OU=Test,DC=Test1,DC=Test2,DC=Test3,DC=com"
$OfficeOU ="OU=Test,DC=Test1,DC=Test2,DC=Test3,DC=com"

#Get Users From AD who are enabled
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$users = get-aduser -filter {memberof -eq $ADGroup} -properties * -searchbase $OfficeOU |where {$_.Enabled -eq "True"} | where { $_.PasswordNeverExpires -eq $false } | where { $_.passwordexpired -eq $false }

foreach ($user in $users)
{
$Name = (Get-ADUser $user | foreach { $_.GivenName})
$emailaddress = $user.emailaddress
$passwordSetDate = (get-aduser $user -properties * | foreach { $_.PasswordLastSet })
$PasswordPol = (Get-AduserResultantPasswordPolicy $user)
# Check for Fine Grained Password
if (($PasswordPol) -ne $null)
{
$maxPasswordAge = ($PasswordPol).MaxPasswordAge
}

else
{
$maxPasswordAge = (Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy).MaxPasswordAge
}


$expireson = $passwordsetdate + $maxPasswordAge
$today = (get-date)
$daystoexpire = (New-TimeSpan -Start $today -End $Expireson).Days
$subject="Your Network/Outlook password will expire in $daystoExpire days"
$attachment="C:\Util\Outlook Web App Password Change Procedure.pdf"
$body ="
Dear $name,
<p> Your Network/Outlook password will expire in $daystoexpire days.<br>
Please follow the instructions in the attached guide to change your password. For     assistance, please contact me or send an email to admin@support.com<br>

if ($daystoexpire -lt $expireindays)
{
Send-Mailmessage -smtpServer $smtpServer -from $from -to $emailaddress -subject    $subject -body $body -attachments $attachment -bodyasHTML -priority High

}  

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have gathered a list of group members first using `Get-ADGroupMember $ADGroup -Recursive` and then matched the users against that, ex:

```
$pattern = [regex]::Escape($OfficeOU)

Get-ADGroupMember $ADGroup -Recursive |
Get-ADUser -Properties * |
? { $_.Enabled -and $_.PasswordNeverExpires -eq $false -and $_.passwordexpired -eq $false -and $_.DistinguishedName -match $pattern }
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'll try to to incorporate it and see what I get. I just updated my post to show the whole script so that might give a better picture. I need to get all the AD Properties in that initial Get-ADUser command as I refer to some of the other ones to send the notfication to the user.

Comment: Then simply change it to `-Properties *` like you've done in your script. The only reason I put the two password properties was because they where required for my sample to be valid. :)

Comment: IF this is too much to explain, feel free to tell me! I'm just getting my feet wet with PS. I got this to work by using "Get-ADGroupMember $ADGroup -Recursive | get-aduser -properties * |where {$_.Enabled -eq "True"} | where { $_.PasswordNeverExpires -eq $false } | where { $_.passwordexpired -eq $false }" followed by the rest of my code. What is the advantage/disadvatnage to do it the way your example shows vs mine? I am not using the match and pattern variable.

Comment: The difference is that fewer cmdlets usually equals faster execution, so grouping all the tests in a single `where`-statement is faster and cleaner(remember that `?` is just an alias for `where`). As for the pattern, that was just to match the OU. I wasn't sure if that was a criteria or not, so I included it to be safe.

Comment: Cool..I didn't know the bit about `?` being an alias for `where`. This little project was my first work with PowerShell but I find it much easier to learn when I have a end goal and can work to achieve it. Thanks for you time.